# Python 3.5 - Booleans in expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and would like to find out if I am able to use multiple of Boolean operators in one expression such as:

```
taco = int(input("Enter Tacos:\n"))

if taco == (taco == 3) or (taco == 5) or (taco == 7):
    print("Just an example.")
else:
    print("No taco for you.")
```

Instead of using two "or" operators in the statement, is it possible to make it smaller?  Maybe something like `taco == 3 or 5 or 7`?

Please don't laugh at me; I'm really new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can write `taco in (3, 5, 7)` (though this is not a boolean `or` expression).

Comment: In python3.5, if you're testing against a container of immutable literals, you're slightly better off using a set:  `taco in {3, 5, 7}`

Comment: Sure, but for me in this case it saves about 15ns :) Better if you have a large collection possibly.

Comment: saves 15ns, but you loose nothing, but typing parentheses - and helps setting the mindset. It actually works in Python 2.7 as well.

Comment: Yeah, generally, if you're writing the literals by hand, the time savings aren't going to be much since the collections will always be small.  I guess for me, it's more about the semantics.  `set`s are made to excel at membership tests.  `tuple` are generally used for other things.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. This was for a class assignment and I was getting difficulty with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the possible taco Options into a list. For example:

Options =[3,5,7]

Then your able to do

If taco in Options:
    Print ("example")

Or perhaps more consise you can also do

If tacos in [3,5,7]:
    Print ()